# How to roast garlic on low temperature grill

Tags: grilling, garlic, ribs

Going to smoke some pork ribs on the grill, with a smoker box, planned temp with closed cover is about 90C (194F), but for sure less then the boiling point. This will probably take about 2:30 - 3 hours.
Is there anything I can do to use the space on the grill for roasting some garlic while ribs getting done? I am used to add some oil and cover them in foil, then roast on high temp for about half an hour. But now it is going to be relatively low temps.

Thanks,
UriR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do the same thing - cut the ends off, drizzle on some oil, wrap in foil, and leave them.

Comment: Thanks :) For how long? same 3 hours on low temp? will it get same result as the 30 mins on high temp? will they be even cooked at this 90c temp?

Comment: They'll certainly be cooked. Generally speaking slower cooking is better, so the results should be even better. It may require some trial and error in terms of timing and placement, but garlic grows on trees (figuratively speaking) after all.

Comment: Update - FULL SUCCESS :) 3 hours of garlic with olive oil inside closed foil, for low temp (90-100 C) - great taste!

Comment: Excellent. Another win for low and slow!